# Winphone7 programming ToggleSwitch space

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7

I added ToggleSwitches in the Listbox.

Following are xaml file.

```
<ListBox>
<toolkit:ToggleSwitch Header="" Margin="30,0,0,0" Name="Item1" SwitchForeground="#FFF09609">
<toolkit:ToggleSwitch.ContentTemplate>
<DataTemplate>                                
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
<TextBlock Text="item1" Width="110" Margin="10,0,100, 0"/>
</StackPanel>                                
</DataTemplate>
</toolkit:ToggleSwitch.ContentTemplate>
</toolkit:ToggleSwitch>
</ListBox>
```

My problem is remove top and bottom space in the toggleswitch.
I want to add several ToggleSwitches in the ListBox, but one Toggle Switch has his large top and bottom spacing.
If I reduce ToggleSwitch's height, text and graphics's bottom part is chopped.
What solution to fix this?

Comment: Have you tried modifying the template of the ToggleSwitch in Blend? You have full control over the appearance of all controls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could set Minus values for the Margin of the ToggleSwitch, as follows :-

```
            <StackPanel>
                <toolkit:ToggleSwitch Content="Test"
                                      Margin="0,-20,0,-20" />
                <toolkit:ToggleSwitch Content="Test"
                                      Margin="0,-20,0,-20" />
                <toolkit:ToggleSwitch Content="Test"
                                      Margin="0,-20,0,-20" />
                <toolkit:ToggleSwitch Content="Test"
                                      Margin="0,-20,0,-20" />
            </StackPanel>
```

Comment: Thanks Paul, it works, now I am facing a problem.
one ToggleSwitch has a text and a button.
Text is placing center on the vertical alignment, but button is not aligned.
I want to place them on the vertical center.
Any idea?

Comment: Can you provide a code sample, I suspect you might need to use a grid to layout your controls, but it would be useful to see what you have to start with, maybe a new question is required?

Comment: I already provide code in my original question.
Text "item1" is placed vertical center, but toggle button is placed top. why it does?

Comment: It's not clear what from the XAML you provided the layout you are looking for. I see the item1 text to the left of the toggle button. Are you adding items to the ListBox? Have you looked at setting the VerticalAlignment property?

Comment: Yes, I am adding toggle switches to the ListBox. And set verticalAlignment to the center, but not affected.
item1(Vertical center)     |_|______|(Vertical top)

Comment: Can you provide the code that you are using to add ToggleSwitches to the ListBox, I assume you are doing this in code behind, as the above XAML is only adding a single Toggle Switch to the ListBox.

Comment: I only added them in the xaml.
Each toggle switch's code are exactly same except text name.

Comment: Can you provide the complete XAML?

Comment: <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
            <ListBox>
                <toolkit:ToggleSwitch Header="" Margin="30,0,0,0" Name="item1">
              ...      
                </toolkit:ToggleSwitch>
            </ListBox>
        </Grid>

Comment: I am sorry but you still haven't provided enough XAML for me to reproduce your issue. I want to help you but there isn't enough to go on.

Comment: sorry, but whole xaml exceeds characters limit, so I sent only content header.
I made new page item, and add toggle switch code in the original question to the new page Content section with <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel">...